# Removing File in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am working on a ConsoleApplication in **VS 2010** in WIndows 7, I am having method which deletes a file from disk the code is given below

```
bool DeleteRelFile(char * file)
{
    if (remove(file) == 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Now the problem i am facing is when i run the project in debug mode and pass the filepath to the above method, the file is successfully deleted, but when i run the exe from command prompt then the file passed through the method is not deleted. your help would be appreciated

Comment: can you show us how the entire code?

Comment: Sounds like permissions stuff, try running the .exe as admministrator.

Comment: Well, really, how about checking what error you get, if any... Read docs for *remove* to get started on that.

Comment: If the path is relative: Running from VS or running indepenently can result in different working directories

Comment: When you debug, your directory is possibly not the same as when you start the exe file. Normaly when you debug the execution directory is the project path.

Comment: @DanielSanchez it is already running in admin mode

Comment: @devianfan the path is not relative

Comment: i think creating a log file at different stages might be helpful to you to narrow down where the problem is.

Comment: Without more info about error, actual paths etc, this question is unanswerable, there are many possible reasons and SO is not a guessing game site...

Comment: In case of failure you should use perror to print a human readable error message

Comment: Chances are you can drop your function altogether in favor of the [`DeleteFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363915(v=vs.85).aspx) function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is the path to the file. If you simply pass the file name it will not work because it expects the file to be in the current directory (where you are running the code from); 
You can pass an absolute path like c:\input.txt just to see that it works both ways and figure out the correct relative path after that.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I doubt it is path problem, finally your launch directory is same in debug through MSVC and running exe.

Comment: @Digital_Reality Unless he's running it in the Debug or Release directory.